# Fastest way to import a large undirected graph from .ncol format

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

**Problem:**

I have a large **undirected** graph in the `.ncol` format, and want to get it in to *Mathematica.*

I understand that *Mathematica* doesn't natively support the import of `.ncol` format, but `.ncol` format is very simple...

```
node1 node2 0.1
node2 node3 0.2
node1 node5 0.3
node3 node5 0.9
node2 node5 0.5
```

For example, this `.ncol` file produces the following **undirected** graph...

[image]

**Question:**
What's the best way to import a large, complete, undirected graph of 4268 nodes, and  9105778 edges in `.ncol` format? Is it possible to import this type of file even though it is not natively supported? Reading in line by line?

**What I've Tried So Far**

Thank you *vikram reddy* and *user6014* for your suggestions.

I have implemented `ReadList` as such:

```
list = ReadList["/path/to/file.ncol", Word, RecordLists -> True, 
  WordSeparators -> {" "}]
```

Now, `list` is a nested list of the lines like:

```
{{"0000004", "0000002", "0.8516145163710000"}, {"0000007", "0000006", 
  "0.9169866102280000"}, {"0000011", "0000000", "0.8639846171470000"}...}
```

How do I add these elements to a graph object?

**The `.ncol` File (snippet):**

Here's a snippet of the `.ncol` graph I am actually trying to import:

```
0000001 0000000 0.4408587960080000
0000002 0000000 0.7405196230980000
0000002 0000001 0.5211728712080000
0000003 0000000 0.7376683700760000
0000003 0000001 0.4166055229790000
0000003 0000002 0.6032695565790000
0000004 0000000 0.7225082142750000
0000004 0000001 0.5197121010690000
0000004 0000002 0.8516145163710000
0000004 0000003 0.6050347164500000
0000005 0000000 0.3433514873340000
0000005 0000001 0.4807050687280000
0000005 0000002 0.3554792851080000
0000005 0000003 0.3306190830880000
0000005 0000004 0.3536941923200000
0000006 0000000 0.4033221771690000
0000006 0000001 0.6300091271690000
0000006 0000002 0.4136969934920000
0000006 0000003 0.4107973190560000
0000006 0000004 0.4259157902110000
```

Thank you!

Comment: I do not have your dataset. But why don't you try this?  This is just to import the file.ReadList[inputfilename, Word, RecordLists -> True, 
 WordSeparators -> {" "}]

Comment: Try what exactly?

Comment: Use the code he mentioned, `ReadList[yourFileName, Word, RecordLists -> True, WordSeparators -> {" "}]`, where your file name is the .ncol file. It should bring the data in as a list of strings, to which you can easily then likely modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: OK. It works well, up to that point, but now I need to put all the values in a graph object. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough mock up of how you could handle this, using Vikram's suggestion to import the data:

```
In[4]:= lis=ReadList["yourfileName.ncol", Word, RecordLists->True, WordSeparators->{" "}]

(*Out[4]= {{"0000001", "0000000", "0.4408587960080000"}, {"0000002", "0000000", "0.7405196230980000"}, {"0000002", "0000001", "0.5211728712080000"}, {"0000003", "0000000",   "0.7376683700760000"}, {"0000003", "0000001", "0.4166055229790000"}, {"0000003", "0000002",   "0.6032695565790000"}, {"0000004", "0000000", "0.7225082142750000"}, {"0000004", "0000001",   "0.5197121010690000"}, {"0000004", "0000002", "0.8516145163710000"}, {"0000004", "0000003",   "0.6050347164500000"}, {"0000005", "0000000", "0.3433514873340000"}, {"0000005", "0000001",   "0.4807050687280000"}, {"0000005", "0000002", "0.3554792851080000"}, {"0000005", "0000003",   "0.3306190830880000"}, {"0000005", "0000004", "0.3536941923200000"}, {"0000006", "0000000",   "0.4033221771690000"}, {"0000006", "0000001", "0.6300091271690000"}, {"0000006", "0000002",   "0.4136969934920000"}, {"0000006", "0000003", "0.4107973190560000"}, {"0000006", "0000004", "0.4259157902110000"}})*
```

Convert string to expressions:

```
exprlis = ToExpression /@ lis;
```

Your graph will likely take the form `Graph[edges, EdgeWeight->weights]`. To achieve this:

```
{edges, weights} = exprlis/. {a_, b_, c_}:>{a\[UndirectedEdge]b,c}//Transpose;
```

And then you can just input `edges` and `weights` into a Graph object:

```
Graph[edges, EdgeWeight -> weights]
```

[image: completed graph]

Comment: +1 - I made a couple of changes, hope you don't mind.  One just to change "vertices" to "edges", and another to reflect that the OP was asking about an undirected graph.

Comment: Ah, I missed the undirected part. Appreciate the corrections!